# Как скопировать файлы из папки в grunt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend, grunt

Мне нужно скопировать все файлы из одной папки в другую, **но при этом копировать нужно только те файлы, которых нет в той папке, в которую я копирую.**

**При этом файлы будем считать одинаковыми если у них одинаковые имена, а само содержимое файлов может различаться. Т.е. проверять на наличие, нужно именно по названию, а не по содержанию файлов.**

Т.е. если у меня есть папка img c файлами foto.png и foto2.png и папка origin c файлом foto.png. То из img в папку origin должен скопироваться только файл foto2.png т.к. файл с именем foto.png в папки origin уже есть и он не должен быть изменён. **Подскажите пожалуйста как решить эту проблему на grunt?**

*Пробовал использовать таск grunt-contrib-copy, но он копирует все файлы в не зависимости от того, есть ли файлы с тем же именем в папке назначения, или нет. Т.е. grunt-contrib-copy скопирует и foto.png и foto2.png...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Оригинальный ответ на английском StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19444209/task-to-create-files-folders-when-they-dont-exist-in-grunt)

[*grunt-contrib-copy*](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy) позволяет фильтровать файлы и определять, какие из них должны быть скопированы:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Node.js модуль для работы с путями
  var path = require('path');

  grunt.initConfig({

    copy: {

      main: {

        expand: true,
        cwd: 'dir1', // откуда копируем
        src: '**',
        dest: 'dir2/', // куда копируем
        filter: function(filepath) {
          var dest = path.join(
            grunt.config('copy.main.dest'),
            // Удаляем фрагмет 'dir1' из пути
            filepath.split(path.sep).slice(1).join(path.sep)
          );
          // проверка на существование файла
          return !(grunt.file.exists(dest));
        }

      }

    }

  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['copy']);

};
```

Выполнить этот пример можно запустив `$ grunt` в терминале (при условии что у вас есть папки `dir1` и `dir2`, заполненные файлами, чтобы увидеть результат).

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-sync
Копирует только файлы с изменениями.

Comment: grunt-sync, как я понимаю, проверяет сами файлы, а мне нужно проверять именно название. Т.е. если файл foto.png есть в обоих папках, то его копировать не нужно, даже если само содержимое этих файлов разное.